# Azure data factory - Dashboard Log Query - Filter failed pipelines who successfully rerun

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've been tasked with reducing monitor overhead of a data lake (~80TiB) with multiple ADF pipelines running (~2k daily). Currently we are logging Failed pipeline runs by doing a query on `ADFPipelineRun`. I do not own these pipelines, nor do I know the inner workings of existing and future pipes, I cannot make assumptions on how to filter these by custom logic in my queries. Currently the team is experiencing fatigue with these, most failed piperuns are solved during their reruns.

How can I filter these failures so they dont show up when a rerun succeeds?

The logs exposes a few id's that initially looks interesting, like `Id`, `PipelineRunId`, `CorrelationId`, `RunId`, but none of these will link a failed pipe to a successful one.

The logs does however show an interesting column, `UserProperties`, that apparently can be dynamically populated during the pipeline run. There may be a solution to be found here, however it would require time and friction for all existing factories to be reconfigured.

Are there any obvious solutions I have overlooked here? Preferably Azure native solutions. I can see that reruns and failures are linked inside ADF Studio, but I cannot see a way to query it externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion with the owner of the ADF pipes we realized the naming convention of the pipelines would allow me to filter out the noisy failing pipes that would later succeed. It's not a universal solution but it will work for us as the naming convention is enforced across the business unit I am supporting